# Slack bot - Sending messages to different users in multiple Workspaces

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to deliver direct messages to different users by using Slack bot. I'll send them based on events of my web app.

But different companies will install my bot in different Workspaces. That also means an user X of company A is in workspace A, and user Y of company B is in Workspace B

My doubts are:

1. If I call API method `users.list` will it include all users from all workspaces that installed the bot?
2. The bot user access token is the same for all workspaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - No. `users.list` will only contain the users for one workspace. The one that is linked to the token you are using in the API call.

2 - No. There is a different bot token for every workspace

Here is how it works.

- A user that wants to use your bot in his workspace needs to first install
  it. During the installation process (via [Oauth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)) a new token
  for that workspace will be generated and you app will need to store
  it. Note that installation has to be once only. The token does not expire.
- When your app receives an event it will contain the team ID (that references the workspace). You app then needs to use the token for
  that workspace to make any API calls.